# How to send mail from bootstrap form on completition and submission to a mail address?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, forms, email

I  have created a bootstrap form .. lets say it is for a survey and it generally has a lot of yes no questions . with radio buttons and some text fields for the name,time, date and remarks.. here i want to send the completely filled form to the mail address of  admin .. what should be done i am using  bootstrap for this..
I tried this but it is not much applicable to me .. it sends the mail but all the forms are not sent by it.. please help..

```
    <?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "emailaddress@here.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

Comment: bootstrap itself wont do this, you'll need php or other language to actually send the email

Comment: ok what should be done to send the completely filled forms as an email...

Comment: what have you tried?. We are not here to write code for you. Look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: The code you've provided us doesn't indicate what fields aren't being sent, but generally you would need to output all of the `$_POST` data in some fashion.  In the above you are only defining `email` and `message` so that's all that is being included in your mail.

Answer (score 0):

Use ini_set to change smtp, port, Authorization details, sendmailfrom etc in this script and then use mail function. Hope it will help.

Ex:-
ini_set("SMTP", "smtp.google.com");

Comment: How does this address the OPs question, which seems to be "How do I include all of my form data in my outgoing mail"

Comment: You need mail settings, so add SMTP settings in the same script, it will temporarily change the php.ini file variables, then create a variable named $content and put all stuffs in it. you can even put html elements. than use mail function like this mail($to, $subject, $content, $header); thats it.

Comment: Re-read the OPs problem. They are trying to output via e-mail values from `$_POST` that they do not include as part of their `$formcontent`.  Changing to SMTP doesn't address that at all.